# Express environment command line

Tags: node.js, express

I need to load an express app into the console so that I could test objects, some data models, work with Sequelize, etc. I need a console for general debugging.

There used to be a way to do this, but I can't remember the trick.

I think it is along the lines of getting into the `node` console and then requiring `app.js` somehow.

I am trying to execute `User.create()` in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sequelize specifically, you will want to use the async flag to troubleshoot. The method below will load all the models

`node --experimental-repl-await`

```
> models = require('./models'); //requires all models
> User = models.User; //however you load the model in your actual app this may vary
> await User.create({name:"Hoosier"}); //use await to avoid promise errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local server wrapping `app` as followed and running `node {local server filename}`. Then the endpoints are available to hit with postman, a browser, or curl

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = 8202;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Postman / Browser:** http://localhost:8202/users

**Curl:**
`curl 'http://localhost:8202/users'`

---

`app` might look something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const User = require('./User);

app.get('/users', (req, resp) => {
    resp.send({
        msg: 'users endpoint',
    });
});

//You will likely want to use postman to handle the post
app.post('/users', (req, resp) => {
    User.Create(req.body);
    resp.send({
        msg: 'user created',
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I am not trying to actually run the app. I just need to be able to use it in a console

Comment: So, I don't need to http into it, just need to be able to get inside the console environment

Comment: I mean you can see whats available in app by doing `node`, `const app = require('./app')`, `app` I don't see a way to call the routes defined yet, but still looking

Comment: If you have your Users model exported correctly you could possibly do `node`, `const User = require('./User')` `User.Create()` But at that point it's not using express

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use it doing express that way. But if your model is set up a certain way you could use node to load your model and call it through that...

User.js

```
module.exports = {
  Create: (data) => { 
    console.log(data);
    //do other stuff
    return true; 
  }
}
```

you can then access it in node...

```
-> node
-> const User = require('./user')
undefined
-> User.Create({test: 'test'})
{test: 'test'}
true
```